# Using replaceWith() to replace commas in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use replaceWith to replace commas with a linebreak in jQuery?

```
var team1 = ["player1", "player2", "player3"]
```

When I prepend the team1 into a table, it shows up like this

```
player1,player2,player3
```

So I tried to use jQuery's `replaceWith` to somehow replace the comma with a linebreak.

```
$(team1).replaceWith('<br>')
```

But that targets the entire team1, and I only want to target the commas or somehow add a linebreak instead of a comma.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you coerce an array to a string, you're indirectly using `.join(",")`. If you want to join with some other delimiter instead, use `join` directly:

```
str = team1.join("<br>");
```

**But**: If the entries in the array are meant to be literal text, not HTML, you first need to escape any characters with special meaning in HTML via `map`:

```
str = team1.map(entry => entry.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;")).join("<br>");
```

---

Also note that jQuery's [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) isn't about replacing characters in strings. It's about replacing HTML elements with other HTML elements. To replace characters in a string, you use String's [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.